# ToString("C") does not show expected result in VB

Tags: vb.net, tostring, render-to-string

The input changes to $0.00 whenever i try this coding:

```
Private Sub btnEnt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnt.Click

    Dim result As String

    Dim earn As Decimal

    txtEarning.Text = earn.ToString("C")

    result = txtFName.Text & " " & txtLName.Text & " Worked" & vbCrLf

    result &= nudHr.Value & " Hrs today"

    result &= " and his earning is " & txtEarning.Text

    txtRes.Text = result

End Sub
```

[image]

instead of displaying input value, the value automatically converts to $0.00

Comment: Why would you expect anything else? You don't set `earn` to anything, so it will be zero, and then you do this: `txtEarning.Text = earn.ToString("C")` What exactly do you think that should do?

Comment: I'm guessing what you actually meant to do was get the input from `txtEarning.Text` and put it into `earn`, not output the value of `earn` to that `TextBox`. In that case you don;t want `ToString` at all because you need to convert FROM a `String`, not TO a `String`. Mind you, you never actually use `earn` again so what would be the point? Maybe you should spend some time thinking about what you're actually trying to achieve, WRITE THAT DOWN and then write code to implement what you wrote down, not some vague impression that's only in your head.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need this:

```
Dim earn as Decimal = nudHr.Value * 20
```

If your person earns 20 dollars an hour